# How to do Edit Text Error Message Verification in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

How to verify this error message, this is not a toast message.

Developers create it through edittxt.setError method, it is generating from that edit text box only but, it can be located through UI automation.

Then how to capture it and verify it.

Please check the image attached.
[App Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxwaX.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently your question is unanswerable because it doesn't include code that you've tried. An edit to include what you've done would help.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the error message (and verify if it exists or not), you can implement the following--

First, a `DoesElementExist` method which checks for the presence of a WebElement, and returns `true` or `false` based on element's existence:

```
public static bool DoesElementExist(this AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement> driver, By locator)
{
    // attempt to locate element
    try
    {
        // return true if found
        return Driver.FindElements(locator).Count > 0;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        // if we catch exception, element does not exist, return false
        return false
    }
}
```

We can call our method to check the error message as such:

```
bool doesErrorMessageExist = driver.DoesElementExist(By.XPath("//*[contains(@text, 'Invalid number')]");
```

This will return true if the error message appears on the page, and false if it does not.

Comment: But i can't find by element as elements , because than i will not be able to send keys to it.

Comment: I’m confused about what you are trying to do here. Do you want to locate the error message and check if it exists or not? What are you trying to send text to, and what is stopping you from just using `element.SendKeys`?

Comment: There is an error showing in the picture saying"Invalid Number.."

Comment: This can not be find through UI automator.\

Comment: I am not able to verify it that this error is showing.

Comment: I need solution for this